# How to excute "LIKE" query in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve data on Firebase by using "LIKE".

> In SQL Server, easy excute "LIKE" by: WHERE column LIKE '%abc%'

And now, how can we do it in Firebase???
**UPDATE**:
 I'm developing on Android, not Web. Is there any APIs to do this?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That duplicate is a JavaScript answer.

Comment: You could always fetch the entire record, then filter out the strings that don't contain the substring.

Comment: Since queries are run server-side, their feature set is exactly the same between all Firebase Database SDKs.